# How do I test functions using pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, user-interface, pytest

*Hello,*

I need your help writing test functions for the following functions using pytest: add_new_user, register_user, login_verify

I am trying to test my login system program using the pytest module which is a requirement for the end-semester project. The following are functions I am having trouble testing:

1. Function without parameters, but rather get information from the user.
2. Function that appends information to a text file.
3. Function that reads from a text file.

Thank you in advance to the good samaritan.

1a) Python File.

```
def add_new_user():
    """The function enables the users to enter their information and register"""

    # Gobal variables
    global username
    global password
    global fullname
    
    global username_entry
    global password_entry
    global fullname_entry

    global new_user_window

    
    # Creates another window on top of the main menu window
    # for the user to enter their information.
    new_user_window = Toplevel(main_window)
    new_user_window.title("New User")
    new_user_window.geometry("300x300")
    
    # Create a string variable that corresponds to the user's
    # username, password and full name
    username = StringVar()
    password = StringVar()
    fullname = StringVar()

    # Create "fill information" label.
    label2 = Label(new_user_window, text = "Please fill in the info below", bg="gray", fg="pink")
    label2.pack(fill=X, pady=20)
    
    # Create username's label and the entry box for a user input
    user_info_panel = Frame(new_user_window)
    user_info_panel.pack(pady=20)
    username_label=Label(user_info_panel, text="Username: ")
    username_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    username_entry = Entry(user_info_panel, textvariable=username)
    username_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    # Create space between the username and password
    Label(user_info_panel, text="").grid(row=1)
    
    # Create password's label and the entry box for a user input
    password_label = Label(user_info_panel, text="Password: ")
    password_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
    password_entry = Entry(user_info_panel, textvariable=password)
    password_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

    # Create space between password and full name
    Label(user_info_panel, text="").grid(row=3)
    
    # Create full name's label and an entry box for the user input
    fullname_label = Label(user_info_panel, text="Full name: ")
    fullname_label.grid(row=4, column=0)
    fullname_entry = Entry(user_info_panel, textvariable=fullname)
    fullname_entry.grid(row=4, column=1)

    # Create registration button for the user to their information. 
    register_btn = Button(new_user_window, text="Register", command=register_user)
    register_btn.pack()
```

b) Test file

```
def test_add_new_user(): 
    """Verify that the add_new_user function works correctly. 
    Parameters: none 
    Return: nothing 
    """ 
    assert add_new_user("username") == "Fred69_Coder" 
    assert add_new_user("password") == "#123kitoVu" 
    assert add_new_user("fullname") == "Fred Okorio"
```

2a) Python file

```
def register_user(): 
    """The function writes the user's confidential information in a text file"""

    # Initialize the False boolean variable
    registered = False

    # Get the information typed by the user in the entry boxes.
    username_text = username.get() 
    password_text = password.get() 
    name_text = fullname.get() 
    try:

        # Create the credentials text file and append the new user information
        # in the already existing file.
        with open("credentials.txt", "a") as credentials:

            # Open the credential text file for reading and store a reference
            # to the opened file in a variable named text_file.
            with open("credentials.txt", "r") as text_file:

                # Read the contents of the text
                # file one line at a time.
                for line in text_file:

                    # Split the data in line variable and store the split
                    # data in the login_info variable.
                    login_info = line.split()

                    # From all the information in the data base extract
                    # username information.
                    if username_text == login_info[1]:
                        registered = True

                        # If the user is already registered
                        if registered:

                            # Clear the user entry boxes
                            username_entry.delete(0, END)
                            password_entry.delete(0, END)
                            fullname_entry.delete(0, END)

                            # For debugging purpose
                            print("user already exist")

                            # Window for a failed login process.
                            failed_registration_window = Toplevel(new_user_window)
                            failed_registration_window.geometry("200x200")
                            failed_registration_window.title("warning!")
                            Label(failed_registration_window, text="user already exists.", 
                                  bg="gray", fg="pink").pack(fill=X, pady=20)

                            # Ok button exits the window
                            ok_btn = Button(failed_registration_window, text="Please login",                                          
                                            width="20",command=lambda:failed_registration_window.destroy())
                            ok_btn.pack(pady=20)

                            else:
                                 credentials.write("Username: "+ username_text + " " + "Password: " + password_text + " " +"Name: "+ name_text + "\n")

                            # Clear the user entry boxes.
                            username_entry.delete(0, END)
                            password_entry.delete(0, END)
                            fullname_entry.delete(0, END)

                            # Window for a successful login process.
                            successful_registration_window = Toplevel(new_user_window)
                            successful_registration_window.geometry("200x200")
                            successful_registration_window.title("Success!")
                            Label(successful_registration_window, text="Sucessfully 
                                  Registered!", bg="gray", fg="pink").pack(fill=X, pady=20)
                            ok_btn = Button(successful_registration_window, text="OK", width="20", command = lambda:successful_registration_window.destroy())
                            ok_btn.pack(pady=20)
    except FileNotFoundError as not_found_err: print(not_found_err)

    except PermissionError as perm_err: print(perm_err)
```

b) Test file

```
def test_register_user(): 
    """Verify that the register_user function works correctly. 
    Parameters: none 
    Return: nothing 
    """
```

3a) Python file

```
def login_verify():
    try:
        user = username_verify.get()
        password = password_verify.get()
        login = False
    
        # Open the credential text file for reading and store a reference
        # to the opened file in a variable named text_file.
        with open("credentials.txt", "r") as text_file:

            # Read the contents of the text
            # file one line at a time.
            for line in text_file:

                login_info = line.split()
                if user == login_info[1] and password == login_info[3]:
                    login = True
                        if login:
                            label1 = Label(login_window, text = "You've logged in successfully", fg="green")
                            label1.pack()
                        else:
                            failed_login_window = Toplevel(login_window)
                            failed_login_window.geometry("200x200")
                            failed_login_window.title("Warning!")
                            Label(failed_login_window, text="Invalid username. Please register", bg="gray", fg="pink").pack(fill=X, pady=20)
                            ok_btn = Button(failed_login_window, text="OK", width="20", command= lambda:failed_login_window.destroy())
                            ok_btn.pack(pady=20)

    except IndexError as index_err:
        print(index_err)
    
    except FileNotFoundError as not_found_err:
        print(not_found_err)

    except PermissionError as perm_err:
        print(perm_err)
```

b) Test file

```
def test_login_verify(): 
    """Verify that the login_verify function works correctly. 
    Parameters: none 
    Return: nothing
    """
```

Comment: What happened with [the same question you asked couple of hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733638/testing-functions-using-pytest-module#71733638), now deleted?

Comment: Please be specific with what help you need.

Comment: NameError: name 'StringVar' is not defined

Comment: @buran Sorry, the question was not well-formatted, I tried editing but did not work out, so I deleted and reposted it.

Comment: @DevangSanghani, I kindly need your help on test files(b parts)!.

Comment: "I am having trouble testing: Function without parameters, but rather get information from the user." Part of the issue is that the function in question **does not** "get information from the user". It simply creates the GUI. To make it testable, you could accept the `StringVar`s to populate as parameters, and `return` the components that were created; then have the test function call the function passing in its own `StringVar`s, populate the form using the values that were passed back, and check the `StringVar` contents.

Comment: Anyway, these are separate questions about how to make code testable, each of which is better answered by following a guide on the topic. You may be able to [find one with an Internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=writing+testable+code+in+python).

Comment: Also, check out the concept of [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Fundamentally, the reason you struggle to test the code is that your test code cannot control the client code's environment - and the reason for that is that the client code is doing the work to check the environment, rather than being told what it needs to know.

Comment: This is why you get told to avoid global variables, separate I/O from computation logic, etc. etc.